# Create an Array which contains a RECTANGLE and an INTEGER

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

```
private Array<Rectangle> livinglamas;
```

I want this Array to contain an integer for every rectangle. This integer should be specified in spawnLama() so every Rectangle contains its own value. How do I do this?

```
private void spawnLama() {
    Rectangle livinglama = new Rectangle();

    livinglama.x = MathUtils.random(-800, -400 - 64);
    livinglama.y = 0;
    livinglama.width = 64;
    livinglama.height = 64;

    livinglamas.add(livinglama);



    lastLamaTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

**and**

```
@Override
    public void render() {
```

...

```
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastLamaTime > 1000000000L) spawnLama();


    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = livinglamas.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle livinglama = iter.next();
        livinglama.x += LamaXBewegung * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(livinglama.y + 64 < -575) iter.remove();
    }
   batch.begin();

    for(Rectangle livinglama: livinglamas) {
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), livinglama.x, livinglama.y);
    }
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

...

Comment: How about using a `Map<Rectangle, Integer>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass it and use the subclass instead of Rectangle:

```
public class RectangleWithInt extends Rectangle {
    public int value;
}
```

Or use Libgdx's ArrayMap. Unlike Java's Map, you can have duplicate keys, and like Array, it is ordered:

```
private ArrayMap<Rectangle, Integer> livinglamas;

//...

livinglamas.put(livinglama, someInt);


//...
Iterator<Entry<Rectangle, Integer>> iter = livinglamas.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    Entry<Rectangle, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    Rectangle lama = entry.key;
    int value = entry.value;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I used the ArrayMap. But this still won't work:  for(Rectangle lama: livinglamas) {
   batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), lama.x, lama.y);
  }                                                                                                      What do I need to change there?

Comment: @AlGrande if you've changed `livinglamas` to be an `ArrayMap<>` then iterating it like that won't work, if that's your issue

Comment: Change `for(Rectangle lama: livinglamas)` to `for(Rectangle lama: livinglamas.keys())`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
private Map<Rectangle, Integer> rectByInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I think what you're looking for is either a minimal wrapper class for `Rectangle` containing an int id:

```
public class RectangleWrapper {
    private int id;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    //getters and setters
}
```

or a map (if you're not concerned with the ordering of the collection you can use `HashMap<>`):

```
Map<Integer, Rectangle> livinglamas = new HashMap<Integer, Rectangle>();
livinglamas.put(1, new Rectangle());//for example
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should make a class called Llama, containing an `int` and a `Rectangle`:

```
class Llama
{
    public int n;
    public Rectangle box = new Rectangle();
}
```

Then in `spawnLama`:

```
Llama livinglama = new Llama();

livinglama.box.x = MathUtils.random(-800, -400 - 64);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just create some wrapper to tie rectangle and integer:

```
public class DataHolder {
    public final Rectangle rect;
    public final int i;

    public DataHolder(Rectangle rect, int i) {
        this.rect = rect;
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

then create array or arraylist of dataHolders:

```
// array of dataholders (fixed size)
DataHolder[] arr = new DataHolder[size];
arr[0] = new DataHolder(someRectangle, someInteger);

// arraylist of dataholders (dynamically expandable size) 
ArrayList<DataHolder> arrlist = new ArrayList<>();
arrlist.add(new DataHolder(someRectangle, someInteger));
```